# jsp post is always calling the unexpected method in controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am very new to Spring and stuff .

I am trying to learn the Spring and used the example provided here
http://elizabetht.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/student-enrollment-using-mybatis-with-spring/

This has a login page and finally it login the user and delegate to success page , now I changed the success page with table of data , reading from database.
What is wanted is once user clicks on submit , the data must be saved to the database and the current table must be updated.

So I edited the success page-

```
 <div id="containers">
<%
StudentLogin name = (StudentLogin)request.getAttribute("name");
List<Cube> personList = (List)request.getAttribute("message");
String userName = name.getUserName();
for(Cube cube: personList){
    String usedBy =  cube.getUsedby().trim();
    boolean alreadyUsed = (usedBy.length()>0);
    String ipAddress = cube.getIp();
    String cubeName = cube.getCubename();
    String details = cube.getDetails();
    String mainClass = (alreadyUsed)?"pricetab":"pricetabmid";
    String buttonName = (alreadyUsed)?"Blocked":"Click Here!";
    String usedBody = (alreadyUsed)?usedBy:userName;
    String buttonclass = (alreadyUsed)?"button":"buttonmid";
    String priceFooterClass =(alreadyUsed)?"pricefooter":"pricefootermid";
%>
    <div class="<%= mainClass%> ">
    <h1> <%= ipAddress%> </h1>
    <div class="price"> 
        <h2> <%= cubeName%> </h2> 
     </div>
         <div class="infos">  
         <h3>  <%= details%> </h3>
         <h2>  <%= usedBody%> </h2>
     </div>
      <div class="<%= priceFooterClass%> ">
        <div class="<%= buttonclass%> ">
          <a href="#" onClick="suc(name)"> <%= buttonName%> </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
</div>
```

Now you can notice onClick in the end , so I provided this script which is supposed to do post call and that must be delegated to a method in controller-

```
 <script>
        function suc(name){
            var username = "";
            var password = "";
            var studentLogin = name;
            $.post('success', { userName : userName,password:password }, function(data) {
                $('#containers').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
            } );
        }

</script>
```

an My controller is -

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class StudentController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class);

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private CubeService cubeService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();        
        model.addAttribute("student", student);     
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {        
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        } else if(studentService.findByUserName(student.getUserName())) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User Name exists. Try another user name");
            return "signup";
        } else {
            studentService.save(student);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Saved student details");
            return "redirect:login.html";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {          
        StudentLogin studentLogin = new StudentLogin();     
        model.addAttribute("studentLogin", studentLogin);
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="success", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String success(Model model) {            
        CubeData cubeData = new CubeData();     
        model.addAttribute("cubeData", cubeData);
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="success", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String success(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cubeData") CubeData cubeData, BindingResult result,Model model) {     
        logger.debugf("sss", result);
        return "signup";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentLogin") StudentLogin studentLogin, BindingResult result,Model model) {
        logger.debug(result);
        logger.debug(studentLogin);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "failure";
        } else {
            boolean found = studentService.findByLogin(studentLogin.getUserName(), studentLogin.getPassword());
            if (found) {        
                List<Cube> cubes = cubeService.getCubes();
                model.addAttribute("name", studentLogin);
                model.addAttribute("message", cubes);
                return "success";
            } else {                
                return "failure";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to run many perm combination , but always on click of the button it delegate me to login page again and throws error userName not found, but I would like to know why its not going to the block of success defined in the controller.

Comment: In suc function, you have given variable name as "username" but when you are accessing that variable you have used "userName" Please check it once....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the url of the post method... changed that and it worked

```
$.post('/test/success.html', { userName : userName,password:password }, function(data) {
                $('#containers').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
            } );
```